# Centering a fixed div,div same size as image

Tags: css, html, center, css-position

So i want to position a fixed div in a center of a screen. This div should also be a container for child divs. Also i want it to display an image (as background).
This is the code for image:

```
.centerdiv > img{
height: 100%;
width: auto;
}
```

I would like to keep it that way, so that browser would always display a full image. 
Currently Im trying to with this html code:

```
<div class="centerdiv "><img src="bgstatic.png">
        </div>
```

I did tried to do it with css (adding image in css code). I don't mind about this part really much.
The basic idea is to have a centered image and menus with fixed position (so they don't scroll) and the rest of page should be on top of it and should be able to scroll.

I have tried with margins:auto, left/right 0/50%,etc... I did get a result i almost want. But the problem was that my container div was bigger then fixed background div, thus I had much trouble to position rest of the page with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
   <div class="centerdiv "><img src="bgstatic.png"></div>
</div>
```

Css

```
 .centerdiv{
               height: 100%;
               width: auto;
               display:inline-block;
               position:fixed;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear.
You're looking to make a static, centered background image?

---

If that's the case, it can be done in just your CSS.

```
body {
    background-image: url('bgstatic.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

This would center, statically, a background image.

Here's a jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/TGpWe/

Comment: sry, but that doesnt work as i want :). thing is, i need it to be fixed for whole page. in this scenario image is fixed only for that div (so if div is moved, image disappears). second, i need will later need to position text on that image, so i need fixed div to be same size as image...

Comment: That's why I affixed it to the body element, not a div. That way it will remain as a static background image for your page. I assume you're not going to move the body elsewhere. :)

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the original aspect ratio:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Example: http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php

Comment: sry, but that doesnt work as i want :). thing is, i need it to be fixed for whole page. in this scenario image is fixed only for that div (so if div is moved, image disappears). second, i need will later need to position text on that image, so i need fixed div to be same size as image...